# Change the font color in a QMessageBox PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to change all the font color to white in a MessageBox content but it doesn't change the a href font color to white, too.
Here's the code:

```
def MsgBox(self):
        qmsgBox = QMessageBox()
        qmsgBox.setStyleSheet('QMessageBox {background-color: #2b5b84; color: white;}\n QMessageBox {color: white;}\n QPushButton{color: white; font-size: 16px; background-color: #1d1d1d; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; text-align: center;}\n QPushButton:hover{color: #2b5b84;}')
        QMessageBox.about(qmsgBox, 'SuperPyQtCalculator',
            """<font color='white'><p><b>SuperPyQtCalculator</b></p>
            <p><b>Version:</b> {0}</p>
            <p><b>Author: </b> {1}</p>
            <p><b>Web:</b> <a href='www.linuxmusica.com'>Linux Music 3.0</a></p>
            <p><b>Copyright:</b>  &copy; 2014 Qtrac Ltd.
            All rights reserved.
            <p>This application can be used to calculate
            simple math science operations.</p>
            <p><b>You are using:</b></p>
            <p>Python {2} - Qt {3} - PyQt {4} on {5}</p></font>""".format(
            __version__, __author__, platform.python_version(),
            QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR, platform.system()))
```

I cannot change the a href color with the stylesheet and with the html atribute.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I've already found a solution, it's not the optimal one but it works to me. It consists to aply "font color" directly to the a href text, not to the a href. Here's the code:

```
def MsgBox(self):
        qmsgBox = QMessageBox()
        qmsgBox.setStyleSheet('QMessageBox {background-color: #2b5b84; color: white;}\nQPushButton{color: white; font-size: 16px; background-color: #1d1d1d; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; text-align: center;}\n QPushButton:hover{color: #2b5b84;}')
        QMessageBox.about(qmsgBox, 'SuperPyQtCalculator',
            """<font color='white'><p><b>SuperPyQtCalculator</b></p>
            <p><b>Version:</b> {0}</p>
            <p><b>Author: </b> {1}</p>
            <p><b>Web:</b></font><a href='www.linuxmusica.com'><font color='black'>Linux Music 3.0</font></a></p>
            <font color='white'><p><b>Email: </b>lopeztobal@gmail.com</p>
            <p><b>Copyright:</b>  &copy; 2014 Qtrac Ltd.
            All rights reserved.
            <p>This application can be used to calculate
            simple math science operations.</p>
            <p><b>You are using:</b></p>
            <p>Python {2} - Qt {3} - PyQt {4} on {5}</p></font>""".format(
            __version__, __author__, platform.python_version(),
            QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR, platform.system()))
```